# Can Windows be installed on a n Android Phone

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, android-pc, android-mini-pc

Well I have a Lenovo K3 Note and would like to know if I could install windows on it if so could anyone tell me how because I've done my research and only ended up with tutorials and videos that use a software called change my software and while researching this software I came up with a few isuues some people say its malware and some say that its useless and will only brick my phone if you could provide me a method of installing windows on an Android phone and dual booting it with android I'd be greatful

Comment: There are people who managed to install Windows on Android (probably utilizing VM), but I can't explain for the technical detail.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but installing Windows is not an Android-related question, and thus off-topic here.

Comment: @AndrewT. There is a VM for Android? Would you please enlighten a bit? I'm all ears here, and they are itching to hear. May be in the [chat] if not here.

Comment: @Firelord not sure if it can be called as VM, but [this link](http://m.instructables.com/id/Run-Windows-XP-on-Android-Device/?ALLSTEPS) explains it better than me.

Comment: You might be able to install Linux but not Windows because it is close source

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.

I'm afraid there is little support in the area of custom flashing for your device as it is, even on the Android side.

[This topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/ufficial-thread-lenovo-k3-note-t3102997) on XDA guides you to root the device and install a custom recovery but doesn't give any links ROMs, which you'd need. There is, however, a topic that allows you to install Cyanogenmod 12.1 (Android 5.1.1) [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/rom-lenovo-k30-t-cm12-1-android-5-1-1-t3111084). Note that this is a not officially supported ROM and by the looks of the comments there appear to be quite some issues at the time being.

That doesn't mean all hope is lost. There are rumours by reputable resources that Microsoft is working on a way to install Windows 10 (partially) on an Android device but I wouldn't count on it arriving any time soon. Even if it is, there is no way of saying it'll be compatible with the K3 Note. The question is **why** you need this operating system. If it's specific Microsoft apps you're looking for, there's already a wide range of them available on Android (and iOS) such as Cortana (beta), Bing, Outlook or Word.

Virtualization can be a solution for you but you'll need a running Windows machine to connect your device to. Just Google for "run Windows programs on Android" and you'll find plenty easy-to-follow tutorials to get it done.

As for dualbooting, you'd be roaming dangerous territory. Dualbooting on an Android device is completely different from your average home PC dualbooting Windows and Ubuntu. There are tools like MultiROM, Safestrap, DualBoot Patcher and GRUB for Android but they are in most situations highly experimental.

I hope this helps you in the right direction and at least answers a part of your problem. Whatever you do, make a nandroid backup so if you get in trouble, you can still restore your original setup.

Comment: Thank you for 5he answer well I was planning on runn8ng some programming toold on windows mobile while on the go which virtualization can't solve seamlessly as for dualbooting I was just ask8ng if I can dualboot with windows and android installed but since windows isnt available 8n Android that is pretty much answered I'm already using  MultiROM for dualbooting